# Best $C$ such that $\sum\limits_{1\leq i<j\leq n}|z_i-z_j|\leq C\sum\limits^n_{i=1}|z_i|$ subject to $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n z_i = 0$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, absolute-value

> Find the smallest real $C$ (as a function of $n$) such that $$\sum\limits_{1\leq i<j\leq n}|z_i-z_j|\leq C\sum\limits^n_{i=1}|z_i|$$ for all complex numbers $z_k$'s with $\sum_{i=1}^n z_i = 0$.

This question was [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511477/the-minimum-value-of-c-satisfies-for-any-complex-numbers-z-1-cdots-z-n-who) recently, and closed because the question does not meet Mathematics Stack Exchange guidelines.

I repost it since it is meaningful to related inequalities.

Using the triangular inequality, we have $\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}|z_i-z_j| \le \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n} (|z_i| + |z_j|) = (n-1)\sum_{i=1}^n |z_i|$.

Letting $z_k = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{2\pi (k-1)}{n}}, ~ k=1, 2, \cdots, n$, we have $\sum_{k=1}^n z_k = 0$ and $\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}|z_i-z_j| = n \cot \frac{\pi}{2n}$ which gives $C \ge \cot \frac{\pi}{2n}$.

Also, I found the following result (however the bound is weak for the case here):

Theorem 3.4 in [1]: Let $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$ be complex numbers. Let $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $r\ne 0$ and $s \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Then
$$\left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right|^r + \sum_{1\le i < j\le n} |a_i - a_j|^r\right)^{1/r}
\le C \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^s\right)^{1/s}$$
where
$$C = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
 m^{1/r - 1/2}n^{1/2 + 1/p - 1/s} & \mathrm{if} ~ r \le 2,~  p = \min(2, s),~ m = n(n-1)/2 \\[9pt]
 n^{1/r + 1/q - 1/s} & \mathrm{if} ~ r > 2, ~ q = \min(s, r'), ~ \frac{1}{r} + \frac{1}{r'} = 1.
\end{array}
\right.$$

**Question**: What is the minimum of $C$, as a function of $n$ ?

$\phantom{2}$

*Reference*

[1] Lech Maligranda and Lars-Erik Persson, “On Clarkson's Inequalities and Interpolation,” Mathematische Nachrichten, vol. 155, no. 1, pp. 187-197, Jan. 1992.

Comment: If all $z_j$ have the same modulus then $\cot(\pi/(2n))$ is an upper bound, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2048082/42969. This may or may not help to solve the general problem.

Comment: Side note: I would avoid using $i$ as an index when dealing with complex numbers :)

Comment: @MartinR By the way, I use $\mathrm{i}$ such as $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} x}$, and never use $i$ for complex numbers. (Also, I use $\mathrm{e}$, and don't use $e$ for the constant.)

Comment: @MartinR The question in your link is interesting. It reminds me the conjecture below. Is there some relation between them?  Let $0\le a_1 \le a_2 \le \cdots \le a_n \le \pi$. Prove or disprove that
$$\sum_{1\le i < j \le n} \sin (a_j - a_i) \le \frac{n}{2}\cot \frac{\pi}{2n}.$$

Comment: Using triangular inequality directly, you will have $n-1$? Or am I making mistake?

Comment: @Youem You are right. The bound there is too weak for that case.

Comment: nice problem. Looks like you can square and bash to show that the cotangent bound is optimal for $n = 3.$

Comment: @dezdichado If so, it is helpful.

Comment: never mind - it's much simpler than we thought.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the link. I can prove this inequality https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458827/inequality-with-condition-sum-limits-1-leq-i-j-leq-n1-x-ix-j-sum-limits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much simpler than everyone thought. Take $z_1 = z = - z_2$ and everything else $0.$ Then:
$$\sum_{i<j}|z_i-z_j| = 2(n-1)|z|\leq C\sum_{i}|z_i| = 2C|z|\implies C\geq n-1.$$
But the trivial triangle inequality bound prove this one is optimal.

Comment: It is surprising.